# Entire function mapping a circle to a line

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem says:

Let $f$ be an entire function, $S$ a circle of positive radius and $L$ a line in the complex plane such that $f(S) \subseteq L$. Show that $f$ is constant.

- It would look like an application of the open mapping theorem, however I don't know if the disc enclosed by $S$ is inside of $L$ in order to apply it (this is probably false, although I can't think of an example). Also, looking a the hypothesis that wouldn't really require $f$ to be entire. There is something more to it.

Comment: This really reminds me of inversion, you should go see the tristam needham complex analysis book

Comment: @Buraian : my first reflex has been as you to think to inversion. But the conclusion "f constant" cancels the hope it is inversion. The point is that the circle which is mapped onto a line must pass through the origin and the origin is sent ... nowhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By translation and rotation (replacing $f$ by $g(z)=f(\alpha z)-c, |\alpha|=1$) we can assume $L$ is the real line;

$f(S) \subseteq L$ plus $f$ continuous and $S$ compact connected, means $f(S)=[a,b], -\infty <a \le b < \infty$.

Assuming $f$ nonconstant, it follows $f$ is open so $f(\mathbb D)=U$ is open set and its boundary is included in $f(S)=[a,b]$

(obviously, if $w \in \partial U$ there exists $f(z_n)=w_n \to w, |z_n| <1$ and by openness $z_n$ cannot accumulate except at the boundary, while by the compactness of the closed unit disc, $z_n$ has at least one limit point which then is in $S$)

But now if $U$ is an open set with boundary included in $[a,b]$ we get that $U$ must be unbounded and that contradicts the fact that the closed unit disc is compact, hence $U$ is bounded! So $f$ must be constant.

Note that we only used that $f$ is holomorphic on the open unit disc and continuos on its boundary in addition to $f(S) \subseteq L$

Comment: Can you please explain why if $U$ is open with its boundary contained in $[a, b]$, it implies U is unbounded? And also, are you assuming that $S$ is the unit circle in the complex plane?

Comment: because then $U$ contains $\mathbb C -[a,b]$ as if you fix a point $c$ in $U$, then for any $z \in\mathbb C -[a,b]$, there is a curve joining them and avoiding $[a,b]$ so $z$ must be in the same component of $U$ as $c$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on that curve argument? I know U is path connected and open, but why would the whole curve be in U? Or am I misunderstanding the idea?

Comment: because if it would not be in $U$ it must intersect the boundary of $U$ hence $[a,b]$ (it starts at a point in $U$ so to get outside, it must pass through the boundary!) - this is a general result in the plane, namely that if the boundary of an open set $U$ doesn't disconnect the plane, the open set $U$ is precisely $\mathbb C-\partial U$

Answer (score 3):

As Conrad said, we can assume that $f(S) \subset \Bbb R$. Then $v = \operatorname{Im}(f)$ is harmonic with $v(z) = 0$ on $S$. It follows that $v= 0$ in the interior of $S$.

Then the Cauchy-Riemann equations imply that $f$ is constant in the interior of $S$.

Finally the identity theorem shows that $f$ is constant in $\Bbb C$.

Alternatively one can consider $g(z) = e^{if(z)}$ which is entire, non-zero, and satisfies $|g(z)| = 1$ for all $z \in S$. The maximum modulus theorem implies that $g$ (and therefore $f$) is constant in the interior of $S$, which again implies that $f$ is constant everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you may assume that $L$ is the real axis, so use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.